# How does CIMedianFilter works? (Algorithm)

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, core-image, cgimage

How does the CIMedianFilter works? I mean the algorithm for it, I want it for noise removal, I tried doing it by this code:

```
                // -------------------------- W O R K I N G   O N   R E D -----------------
                // red pixels
                NSNumber *red1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rgbaPixel1[3]];
                NSNumber *red2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rgbaPixel2[3]];
                NSNumber *red3 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rgbaPixel3[3]];
                NSNumber *red4 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rgbaPixel4[3]];
                NSNumber *red5 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rgbaPixel5[3]];

                // red array
                NSMutableArray *redArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:red1, red2, red3, red4, red5, nil];
                // sorting
                NSSortDescriptor *lowToHigh = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
                [redArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lowToHigh]];
                // getting median
                int redMedian = [[redArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
                // setting the pixels red value to the median
                rgbaPixel1[3] = redMedian;
                 /////////////////////////////////testing if sorting and median is true
                 //            NSLog(@"Sir, here's a test (%@, %@, %@, %@, %@) and the median is %i", [redArray objectAtIndex:0],
                 //                                                                                    [redArray objectAtIndex:1],
                 //                                                                                    [redArray objectAtIndex:2],
                 //                  [redArray objectAtIndex:3], [redArray objectAtIndex:4], shit);
                // ---------------------------- E N D   O F   R E D ------------------------

                // ----------------------------- W O R K I N G   O N   G R E E N ---------------
                // getting green pixels first
                NSNumber *green1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:rgbaPixel1[2]];
                NSNumber *green2 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:rgbaPixel2[2]];
                NSNumber *green3 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:rgbaPixel3[2]];
                NSNumber *green4 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:rgbaPixel4[2]];
                NSNumber *green5 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:rgbaPixel5[2]];

                // creating array of greens
                NSMutableArray *greenArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:green1, green2, green3, green4, green5, nil];
                // sorting the array
                [greenArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lowToHigh]];
                // getting the median
                int greenMedian = [[greenArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue];

                // setting the pixels green value to median value
                rgbaPixel1[2] = greenMedian;
                // ---------------------------- E N D   O F   G R E E N ------------------------

                // -------------------------- W O R K I N G   O N  B L U E ---------------------
                // getting blue pixel
                NSNumber *blue1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:rgbaPixel1[1]];
                NSNumber *blue2 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:rgbaPixel2[1]];
                NSNumber *blue3 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:rgbaPixel3[1]];
                NSNumber *blue4 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:rgbaPixel4[1]];
                NSNumber *blue5 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:rgbaPixel5[1]];

                // creating array for blue values
                NSMutableArray *blueArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:blue1, blue2, blue3, blue4, blue5, nil];
                // sorting the array of blues
                [blueArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lowToHigh]];
                // getting the median
                int blueMedian = [[blueArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue];


                // setting pixel blue value to the median we just got :)
                rgbaPixel1[1] = blueMedian;

                // --------------------------------- E N D   O F   B L U E ----------------------
```

but it doesn't have that much effect! or maybe I'm getting the RGB values the wrong way, I really need some help in this.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for CIMedianFilter, as I don't know the specifics of what Core Image does there, but I've written a median filter for my GPUImage framework and I can describe the process there.

First, I should say that what you're doing above by using hefty objects in NSNumber and NSMutableArray is going to be terrible, performance-wise, when iterating over the pixels of an image. Also, memory management of all of those autoreleased objects will be tricky. You at least need to move to scalar types and C arrays for this, and inlined functions for sorting. Better still, you could migrate that to the GPU.

The GPU-based implementation I have in GPUImage is based on the ["A Fast, Small-Radius GPU Median Filter"](http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/papers/MedianShaderX6/) chapter by Morgan McGuire and Kyle Whitson in ShaderX6. This paper describes some optimizations that can be used to speed up GPU-side median filtering in a fragment shader. My implementation of their 3x3 median filter within a fragment shader looks like the following:

```
 precision highp float;

 varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 leftTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 rightTextureCoordinate;

 varying vec2 topTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 topLeftTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 topRightTextureCoordinate;

 varying vec2 bottomTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 bottomLeftTextureCoordinate;
 varying vec2 bottomRightTextureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

#define s2(a, b)                temp = a; a = min(a, b); b = max(temp, b);
#define mn3(a, b, c)            s2(a, b); s2(a, c);
#define mx3(a, b, c)            s2(b, c); s2(a, c);

#define mnmx3(a, b, c)          mx3(a, b, c); s2(a, b);                                   // 3 exchanges
#define mnmx4(a, b, c, d)       s2(a, b); s2(c, d); s2(a, c); s2(b, d);                   // 4 exchanges
#define mnmx5(a, b, c, d, e)    s2(a, b); s2(c, d); mn3(a, c, e); mx3(b, d, e);           // 6 exchanges
#define mnmx6(a, b, c, d, e, f) s2(a, d); s2(b, e); s2(c, f); mn3(a, b, c); mx3(d, e, f); // 7 exchanges

 void main()
 {
     vec3 v[6];

     v[0] = texture2D(inputImageTexture, bottomLeftTextureCoordinate).rgb;
     v[1] = texture2D(inputImageTexture, topRightTextureCoordinate).rgb;
     v[2] = texture2D(inputImageTexture, topLeftTextureCoordinate).rgb;
     v[3] = texture2D(inputImageTexture, bottomRightTextureCoordinate).rgb;
     v[4] = texture2D(inputImageTexture, leftTextureCoordinate).rgb;
     v[5] = texture2D(inputImageTexture, rightTextureCoordinate).rgb;
//     v[6] = texture2D(inputImageTexture, bottomTextureCoordinate).rgb;
//     v[7] = texture2D(inputImageTexture, topTextureCoordinate).rgb;
     vec3 temp;

     mnmx6(v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5]);

     v[5] = texture2D(inputImageTexture, bottomTextureCoordinate).rgb;

     mnmx5(v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5]);

     v[5] = texture2D(inputImageTexture, topTextureCoordinate).rgb;

     mnmx4(v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5]);

     v[5] = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).rgb;

     mnmx3(v[3], v[4], v[5]);

     gl_FragColor = vec4(v[4], 1.0);
}
```

This is fast enough to run against live video on an iOS device, but the 3x3 radius is small enough that you don't see a dramatic change in the final image. It provides a small amount of spatial denoising, but you might need to expand to a 5x5 area to see a more dramatic denoising effect. That will also start to slightly blur the image, so there's a bit of a tradeoff there. With video, you might be able to couple this with a low-pass filter at a gentler strength to do a bit of temporal denoising as well.

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to adapt the above paper to cases larger than 3x3.

Answer (score 0):

An OpenGL ES 3.0 alternative to the code above follows:

```
kernel vec4 medianUnsharpKernel(sampler u) {
vec4 pixel = unpremultiply(sample(u, samplerCoord(u)));
vec2 xy = destCoord();
int radius = 3;
int bounds = (radius - 1) / 2;
vec4 sum  = vec4(0.0);
for (int i = (0 - bounds); i <= bounds; i++)
{
    for (int j = (0 - bounds); j <= bounds; j++ )
    {
        sum += unpremultiply(sample(u, samplerTransform(u, vec2(xy + vec2(i, j)))));
    }
}
vec4 mean = vec4(sum / vec4(pow(float(radius), 2.0)));
float mean_avg = float(mean);
float comp_avg = 0.0;
vec4 comp  = vec4(0.0);
vec4 median  = mean;
for (int i = (0 - bounds); i <= bounds; i++)
{
    for (int j = (0 - bounds); j <= bounds; j++ )
    {
        comp = unpremultiply(sample(u, samplerTransform(u, vec2(xy + vec2(i, j)))));
        comp_avg = float(comp);
        median = (comp_avg < mean_avg) ? max(median, comp) : median;
    }
}

return premultiply(vec4(vec3(abs(pixel.rgb - median.rgb)), 1.0)); 
}
```

As you can see, this is more compatible with older devices, using just a subset of OpenGL; and, I believe it probably runs faster (it's shorter). I could probably double the speed by storing the pixel values from the first pass into an array, and then calling them for the second pass from the array.

It's also easier to comprehend, in that it consists of, basically, two steps:
1. Calculate the mean of the values of the pixels surrounding the source pixel in a 3x3 neighborhood;
2. Find the maximum pixel value of all pixels in the same neighborhood that are less than the mean.
3. [OPTIONAL] Subtract the median pixel value from the source pixel value for edge detection.

If you're using the median value for edge detection, there are a couple of ways to modify the above code for better results, namely, hybrid median filtering and truncated media filtering (a substitute and a better 'mode' filtering). If you're interested, please ask.

Comment: I don't understand your algorithm to calculate the median from the mean. For the array (0, 100, 100), the mean is 67, and the highest value < 67 is 0, which isn't the median.

Comment: I duplicated Brad Larson's filter, exactly and to the letter. If the math doesn't add up, don't look to me. There are a million web sites that tell you how to calculate the median from the mean(?); reference any of them for your own needs, if necessary.